# Pushing Divs down after .Slidetoggle is activated

Tags: html, push, slidetoggle

I am trying to push down the boxes after the .slidetoggle panel is activated. But what happens is that it either goes over or under (depending on z-position) the positioned boxes. I want to it so that when the slidetoggle panel is activated, it will push down all of the boxes.

**Here is the JSFIDDLE:**  http://jsfiddle.net/iqab/8QHdB/3/

And here is an example of the type of functionality I am talking about: 
http://www.michaelnagy.at/

Comment: Looks like you're using `position:absolute` style, thus it has no layout space. So all positioning must be done via script. This kind of display are usually implemented using `overflow-y:hidden` style for the panel and by modifying the panel height.

Comment: something like this: `$(".hox").each(function(){
    $(this).css("height", $(this).height() + "px");
    });`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the CSS with this. The modified lines are commented.
Other fixes applied (see comments in CSS).

```
.wrapper{
    width:800px;
    /*height:800px;*/ /*let wrapper auto resize itself based on contents height*/
    border:solid thin #000;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
}

.wrapper .Boxes{
    display:inline-block; /*fix for box overlap out of wrapper. replacement for "float:left" below*/
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    /*float:left;*/ /*fix for box overlap out of wrapper. replaced with "display:inline-block" above*/
    border:solid thin #000;
    margin:33px;            
}

.wrapper .hbox{
    width:734px;
    height:400px;
    border:solid thin #100;
    /*position:absolute;*/ /*fix for panel overlap over boxes*/
    top:33px;
    margin:33px;
    display:none;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Jay, you are a miracle! I have a couple of questions though: so basically, I just have to adjust the CSS not the java script? Also, I should not have a specified height for wrapper?

Comment: All elements height are `auto` by default, based on each content height. Since originally, the `wrapper` content contains an element with `float` and `absolute` position, the total content height will be less. Specifying the `wrapper` width will limit its height, thus causes boxes to go outside the wrapper. So you shouldn't specify the height if you want it to be dynamic/auto.

Comment: Hi @Jay can you look at this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/iqab/NPRfM/1/) when you have the chance, it's related to the same code, but different JQuery, here is the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032819/transition-between-multiple-slidetoggle-divs) related to the jsfiddle.