# Transition between multiple slideToggle divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, slidetoggle

The basic functionality of my webpage is that I will have thumbnails, `.thnail` which will display a project, when clicked, a drop down panel, `.dropdown`, will slide down to show images (carousel plug in) of projects with respect to the thumbnail clicked.The functionality is almost there, but the transition between clicking the thumbnails is really abrupt. I want the panel to slideUp and then slideDown once ANOTHER thumbnail is selected.

The catch is that I need the `.dropdown` and `.thnail`to be separate, they cannot be a parent/child due to the fact that I am using a complex plug in for my carousel.

**HERE IS MY [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/iqab/NPRfM/1/)**

I found this [tutorial](http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/SCKhf/)
 , but I am having trouble implementing it because it's based off parent/child relationship while my html is based off of ID relationships.

Secondly, is there a way to relate my ID's via `rel="..."` instead of `href="#"` ? Does it matter?

Comment: shouldn't this have the `javascript` tag attached?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPRfM/3/) to slide multiple elements. You might notice that the elements below the dropdowns would "shake" when switching between dropdown.

Take alook at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPRfM/3/) to minimize that shaking. The top ones are the exact same one as above, and the bottom ones are the variation.

Comment: thank you very much! But I was wondering, is there a way that when I click from Red to Green (or between any other color), the Red Slides UP and the green slides down? It seems like the green slides over the red. [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/SCKhf/) Again, thank you for all your help and I will be working on the code aswell!